# awk sed filter values in all lines greater/smaller than

Tags: bash, sed, awk

is there a way to construct a filter in awk (or something similar) that for a given file, say:

```
0.99,0.98,1.1,0.85,0.92
0.76,1.4,0.99,0.99,0.82
1.0,1.45,0.78,0.91,0.95
```

would replace any record in a line that is greater than 1.0 with 1.0?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is something you can do with `awk`

```
awk -F, '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i>1) {$i="replacement"}}1' OFS=, file
```

#### Test:

```
$ cat file
0.99,0.98,1.1,0.85,0.92
0.76,1.4,0.99,0.99,0.82
1.0,1.45,0.78,0.91,0.95

$ awk -F, '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i>1) {$i="replacement"}}1' OFS=, file
0.99,0.98,replacement,0.85,0.92
0.76,replacement,0.99,0.99,0.82
1.0,replacement,0.78,0.91,0.95
```

Comment: Hi, great! Thanks a million. One question, what does `1` in '...}}1' stand for? @Jaypal

Comment: You are most welcome. `1` at the end is to trigger default action of `awk` which is `print`. You can either use any value great than `0` or be verbose and do `awk -F, '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i>1) {$i="replacement"}; print}' OFS=, file`

Comment: @SimonRighley Here is a shorter version: `awk -F, '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) $i=$i>1?"1.0":$i}1' OFS=, file`

Answer (score 4):

Here’s a `sed` solution:

```
sed -e 's/[1-9][0-9]*\.[0-9]*/1.0/g' in-file > out-file
```

The pattern `[1-9][0-9]*\.[0-9]*` simply matches any sequence that begins with a digit greater than `0`, followed by zero or more digits, followed by the decimal point, followed by additional digits. If you want an in-place replacement, you can use the `-i` option:

```
sed -i -e 's/[1-9][0-9]*\.[0-9]*/1.0/g' in-file
```